# From where hadoop gets JAVA_HOME variable value?

Tags: hadoop

I have set `JAVA_HOME` correctly and when I `echo` it, I see the correct value:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/
```

I have also put the `JAVA_HOME` value to the **hadoop-env.sh**.

```
$ grep JAVA_HOME conf/hadoop-env.sh 
# The only required environment variable is JAVA_HOME.  All others are
# set JAVA_HOME in this file, so that it is correctly defined on
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/"
```

Despite all of this, hadoop still shows the `JAVA_HOME` variable totally different. I dont know where it gets this value. Any suggestions?

```
$ hadoop noname -format
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

/usr/bin/hadoop: line 320: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/hadoop: line 390: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I don't see where you show that Hadoop thinks `$JAVA_HOME` is different, only that it can't locate a specific Java. Is it possible there's a simlink/etc to where the error is? Have you looked at the script to see what it does with `$JAVA_HOME`? I mean, it gets `$JAVA_HOME` from `$JAVA_HOME`, AFAIK.

Comment: JAVA_HOME directory is JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/". But, hadoop "thinks" that it is "usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun". In hadoop script JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME. And also hadoop classpath shows /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/lib/tools.jar, which should be /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar.

Comment: And if you echo `$JAVA_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME` in the shell script after `JAVA_HOME` is set (in `hadoop`, not `hadoop-env`)? There's really very little that can go wrong here; what OS are you on? What version of Hadoop? Have you set `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` to something non-standard?

Comment: Make sure `/usr/bin/hadoop` is not also overriding the value of `JAVA_HOME` since it is also a shell script.  Also, I'm not sure if this is true of newer versions, but Hadoop may only support the sun JVM and not openjdk.

Comment: My OS is Ubuntu 12.04, kernel version is 3.3.1-030301-generic. Hadoop version is hadoop-1.1.1. I try manually set JAVA_HOME variable in bin/hadoop script. But when you run hadoop script, value overrides by other script, I still don't know which script.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same problem on my Hadoop install as well.  I found in `/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh` JAVA_HOME was hardcoded to be `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun`.  I went ahead and changed it to `${JAVA_HOME}` and that seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Great! Lots of tutorials failed to mention this.

Comment: If Hadoop had just excluded the `-6-sun` part, then it would always resolve to the path symlinked by alternatives!

Answer (score 6):

In case anybody faces the same problem, look if /etc/hadoop directory is created. If yes, then point `$JAVA_HOME` variable in `/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh` to appropriate jvm path.

Answer (score 6):

I was having " error **/usr/bin/java**/bin/java doesn't exist "

In ~/.bashrc I had JAVA_HOME set to `/usr/bin/java`. I saw in `hadoop/etc/hadoop-config.sh` that it was using `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java`; which explained that error. Only, it did not fix it to remove /bin/java. To find my answer, I investigated via

```
cd /usr/bin/java
ls -al
```

And I saw

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Jul 22 16:01 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
```

What I noticed most was the the left side of the arrow was Teal and the right side of the arrow was Green, in my bash prompt. I thought it might be a symlink. I did this again this time `ls -al`'ing (the **-al** was very important) symlinked location (see below), and noticed what looked like another symlink.

```
root@groovy:~# ls /etc/alternatives/java -al
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Jul 22 16:01 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

I took ***that*** value on the right of the arrow, and put it in ~/.bashrc

---

### *final configurations*

**~/.bashrc**

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
```

**hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh**

```
export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}
```

**hadoop/libexec/hadoop-config.sh**

```
EXPORT JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Note that I installed the JDK to begin with via `sudo apt-get install default-jdk`

Comment: you can use `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre` in `~/.bashrc` if you are using java-8, in `hadoop/libexec/hadoop-config.sh`, I used `export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME` before `# Attempt to set JAVA_HOME if it is not set` lines in the file, and now it's working

Answer (score 2):

There are two `hadoop-env.sh` files: one in the `conf` subdirectory under your `hadoop` directory, and one under `/etc/hadoop`. You need to change `$JAVA_HOME` in both.

Answer (score 1):

In $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh set

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin
```

In $HADOOP_HOME/libexec/hadoop-config.sh look for and modify `JAVA=$JAVA_HOME/bin/java` to

```
JAVA=$JAVA_HOME/java
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this is not the ideal solution. but this is what I did:

I put echo statements all throughout `/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop` to see when `JAVA_HOME` gets set to a statically (seems static, anyhow) defined path of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun`.

I can tell this happens pretty much right away. And I had no idea why this was happening. I installed java in `/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_17` and correctly set up JAVA_HOME in my path and everything. funny thing, is I dont even have java 6 installed!

so here is the hacky part. I went to where it expected to find java-6-sun, and set a symlink to my java install

```
cd /usr/lib/jvm
sudo ln -s /usr/local/jdk1.7.0_17/ java-6-sun
```

then everything worked. extremely hacky I know, but maybe this post could help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but for me it was different issue. The hadoop script was expecting /opt/hadoop/jdk1.0.7.40 as my Java home. But I set it as /opt/hadoop/jdk1.0.7_40. The underscore made the difference. Now it is working. May be this will be helpfull to someone
Dan

Answer (score 0):

I find a funny solution：
if you `echo $JAVA_HOME`, you may get `/usr/bin/java`
`echo export $JAVA_HOME=/usr/ >> conf/hadoop-env.sh`

Answer (score 0):

complicated your stuff guys ....
I have /usr/lib/java-1.8.0-openjdk_BLABLA
while hadoop wants /usr/lib/java-1.8.0-openjdk_YADIYADA

then I go:
cp -ar /usr/lib/java-1.8.0-openjdk_BLABLA /usr/lib/java-1.8.0-openjdk_YADIYADA

and it' s happy !
no way messing up with all this non-sense confs...